# What's a good and stable C++ tree implementation?

Tags: c++, tree, graph-theory

I'm wondering if anyone can recommend a good C++ tree implementation, hopefully one that is 
stl compatible if at all possible.

For the record, I've written tree algorithms many times before, and I know it can be fun, but I want to be pragmatic and lazy if at all possible. So an actual link to a working solution is the goal here.

Note: I'm looking for a generic tree, not a balanced tree or a map/set, the structure itself and the connectivity of the tree is important in this case, not only the data within.
So each branch needs to be able to hold arbitrary amounts of data, and each branch should be separately iterateable.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I don't know about your requirements, but wouldn't you be better off with a graph (implementations for example in [Boost Graph](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/graph/doc/index.html)) if you're interested mostly in the structure and not so much in  tree-specific benefits like speed through balancing? You can 'emulate' a tree through a graph, and maybe it'll be (conceptually) closer to what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes you are right, and I just came back from looking at Boost::Graph. It seems suitable to my needs (structure), however the documentation is huge! Would've been nice if there was a simpler version of a tree though.

Comment: True, the documentation is daunting. If you are really going to base a serious part of your project on this, I suggest you get the boost graph book. It's clearly written (for as far as a book on this topic can be clear) and fairly comprehensive. Most importantly, it'll get you up to speed quickly.

Comment: I just posted a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40809926/modelling-an-arbitrary-tree-in-c) that asks how to implement such a tree using the Boost Graph Library. Maybe you can point me in the right direction? Thank you very much!

Comment: 10 years later I'm not sure why this is the highest voted answer.  The OP wants a tree and the answer is use Boost Graph because "isn't that what you really want"?  Even though there's no indication that the OP wants a graph, not a tree. And BTW, w.r.t. Boost Graph: it's not a tree, but you can use it to _build_ a tree, especially if you buy a book to get you up to speed quickly. (And I'm speaking as one who already _has_ the book.)

Comment: @davidbak And yet, 10 years ago, the OP answered indicating that indeed this is what he was looking for, and my answer itself says that a graph is not a tree but that you can use one to build one? No idea what the point of your comment is...

Answer (score 19):

Take a look at [this](http://tree.phi-sci.com/).

The tree.hh library for C++ provides an STL-like container class for n-ary trees, templated over the data stored at the nodes. Various types of iterators are provided (post-order, pre-order, and others). Where possible the access methods are compatible with the STL or alternative algorithms are available.

HTH

Comment: Doesn't look bad, but its GNU. That is a very heavy price to pay for a tree

Comment: First of all, this project is not part of GNU. Second, if you talk about the GPL, this is not necessarily any price to pay. It depends on if one wants to publish the code and under what terms.

Comment: He mentions on the homepage to contact him if the GPL doesn't suit. What is a fair price to pay for a tree? How much work/time does it save your project?

Comment: @user18044 with tree.hh, is it possible to move in a bi-directional way  (from father to sons and from son to fathers ) ?

Comment: Hmm, it's small , lack of documentation and slow ... my concern is ... why it is slow :(. Granted that Boost::BGL can be a pain in a ass for allocation due to vector<> strategy, it does however grant pure speed once optimized ( althought preallocation is a pain to do .. ).

Answer (score 9):

I am going to suggest using std::map instead of a tree.

The complexity characteristics of a tree are:

Insert:       O(ln(n))
Removal:  O(ln(n))
Find:         O(ln(n))

These are the same characteristics the std::map guarantees.
Thus as a result most implementations of std::map use a tree (Red-Black Tree) underneath the covers (though technically this is not required).

Comment: I think you mean that most std::map implementations use a tree underneath the covers.  Specifically, many (most?) use a Red-Black tree.

Comment: I though that is what I wrote? But I should note the Red-Black part.

Comment: The nice thing about a (generic)tree is that you can add n children to a branch, and apply operations onto different branches, but std::map abstracts all that away, or uses red-black (child n=2), and abstracts away the structure into a flat interface.

Comment: Being able to operate on a single branch is the whole point or a tree. Examples could be filesystem folders, data layout, scene graphs, language analysis, xml-like structured data, and probably many more cases I can't think of right now.

Comment: But for flat data, yes you are right, a map will do nicely, however personally I prefer a hash for flat data

Comment: OK `std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, int>> wtf;` So how would you implement a "previous sibling" in a node stored in std::map ? how do you store "parent" ? std::map is not an answer to this just because map has underlying tree.

Comment: @nurettin: You will notice that the question was edited after I added this answer. This answers the original question.

Comment: @LokiAstari it seems he edited because he had the same idea (map or map of maps is inadequate for trees) It also seems that this question is ages old, so nevermind :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have (key, value) pairs, but simply keys, use std::set. That uses the same Red-Black tree as std::map.

Answer (score 2):

Ok folks, I found another tree library; [stlplus.ntree](http://stlplus.sourceforge.net/stlplus3/docs/ntree.html). But haven't tried it out yet.

Answer (score -1):

Let suppose the question is about balanced (in some form, mostly red black tree) binary trees, even if it is not the case.

Balanced binaries trees, like vector, allow to manage some ordering of elements without any need of key (like by inserting elements anywhere in vector), but :

- With optimal O(log(n)) or better complexity for all the modification of one element (add/remove at begin, end **and** before & after any iterator)
- With **persistance** of iterators thru any modifications except direct destruction of the element pointed by the iterator.

Optionally one may support access by index like in vector (with a cost of one size_t by element), with O(log(n)) complexity. If used, iterators will be random.

Optionally order can be enforced by some comparison func, but persistence of iterators allow to use non repeatable comparison scheme (ex: arbitrary car lanes change during traffic jam).

In practice, balanced binary tree have interface of vector, list, double linked list, map, multimap, deque, queue, priority_queue... with attaining theoretic optimal O(log(n)) complexity for all single element operations.

<sarcastic> this is probably why c++ stl does not propose it </sarcastic>

Individuals may not implement general balanced tree by themselves, due to the difficulties to get correct management of balancing, especially during element extraction.

There is no widely available implementation of balanced binary tree because the state of the art red black tree (at this time the best type of balanced tree due to fixed number of costly tree reorganizations during remove) know implementation, slavishly copied by every implementers’ from the initial code of the structure inventor, does not allow iterator persistency. It is probably the reason of the absence of fully functionnal tree template.