# Tree libraries in python

Tags: python, tree

Are there any python libraries for data trees?

I mean a tree as a general data structure, not just an xml tree.
(Like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205945), but in python.)

Comment: I believe that you need to specify what kind of tree you are looking for. Or perhaps a simple tuple/list structure would suffice? `("node", [Children nodes])`

Comment: Perhaps if you did a Google search and asked specific questions about the libraries you found, we could help more.  As it is, we can only guess what you're looking for.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[pypi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=search&term=tree&submit=search), the Python Package Index, suggests [tinytree](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/tinytree), [treedict](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/treedict/0.10-beta), [caxes](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/caxes/0.2), [pyavl](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyavl/1.12_1)... these are just the top few after filtering away the many accidental hits (which point to specific tree such as XML ones, AST ones, etc, etc;-).  If you clarify what you want to do with your trees it may be easier to suggest a specific package.

Answer (score 21):

I'm happy with [treelib](https://github.com/caesar0301/pyTree). It addresses my problem. Could use a bit more documentation though. But the code is clear.

Answer (score 4):

Although the [ETE](http://ete.cgenomics.org) library seems to be originally developed to work with Phylogenetic trees, it implements many general features to work with any type of hierarchical tree structures, including programmatic tree drawing and visualization.

There is a comprehensive [tutorial and a reference guide](http://pythonhosted.org/ete2/), in case you want to explore it.

Answer (score 1):

[python-graph](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-graph/) seems to be a fairly thorough and complete package, and can export DOT graphs for use with [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/).

Answer (score -5):

You probably want to look at [cElementTree](http://effbot.org/zone/celementtree.htm).