# Recursive containers in C++?

Tags: c++, recursion, containers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are C++ recursive type definitions possible, in particular can I put a vector<T> within the definition of T ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517231/are-c-recursive-type-definitions-possible-in-particular-can-i-put-a-vectort)

I was looking through some code recently and noticed a data structure similar to the following:

```
class TreeNode {
    std::vector<TreeNode> subNodes;
};
```

As you can see, the container is instantiated with TreeNode before TreeNode has been defined. The code compiles under both GCC and MSVC, but I remember seeing something saying that this is not guaranteed behaviour. Unfortunately I can't find anything in the standard discussing this at all.

How are such containers able to be implemented? Is this behaviour guaranteed by the standard? If this is not guaranteed by the standard, what alternatives do I have to this design?

Comment: There was a question exactly like this earlier.. now I must find it!

Answer (score 2):

This is fine because the `std::vector<T>` class doesn't contain any concrete instances of the type `T` in it: it's typically implemented using pointers.  The template instantiation `std::vector<TreeNode>` does not require the full definition of `TreeNode`.

`std::vector<T>` is usually implemented as a triplet of pointers (though this is not required by the standard):

```
template <typename T>
class vector
{
  ...
  T* start;
  T* end;
  T* end_of_storage;
};
```

If `std::vector<T>` *did* contain concrete instances of `T` in it, then you would have a problem.  The following is not legal C++, because it creates a circular "has a" definition:

```
template <typename T>
class container
{
  T x;
};

class TreeNode
{
  container<TreeNode> subNodes;
};
```

Comment: That's interesting but doesn't the full `std::vector` implementation have to get pulled in when `include`ing vector? In which case doesn't the size of type T have to be known? How might the implementation solve this problem?

Comment: You're "right", so I won't downvote, but the standard specifies that using an incomplete type for a template parameter for a standard library template leads to undefined behavior, so technically the answer is "No, you cannot do this."