# Incomplete type error in BGL when using bundled properties

Tags: c++, boost, undefined-behavior, boost-graph

I had this code compiling correctly on some g++ 4.x version, now version 4.6 terminates compilation with an error:

```
/usr/include/boost/pending/property.hpp:35:7: error: ‘boost::property<Tag, T, Base>::m_value’ has incomplete type
```

The error seems to be caused by the loop between the graph_type and the edge_info type declarations.

I was able to isolate the problem in the following few lines of code. How can I use a type that depends on a bundled property of the nodes to define a property of the edges? The solution should still use bundled properties (because a lot of code depends on this graph type). How can I correct the following code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

template<typename map_type>
struct map_computation {
  map_type m;
};

struct vertex_info;
struct edge_info;

typedef adjacency_list<vecS, 
               vecS, 
               bidirectionalS, 
               vertex_info, 
               edge_info> graph_type;

struct position {
  double x, y;
};

struct vertex_info {
  position p;
};

typedef boost::property_map<graph_type, 
                position vertex_info::*>::type position_map_type;

struct edge_info {
  map_computation<position_map_type>* c;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  graph_type g;
  return 0;
}
```

EDIT: the complete error log reads:

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp:22:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp:33,
                 from gtest.cc:2:
/usr/include/boost/pending/property.hpp: In instantiation of ‘boost::property<boost::edge_bundle_t, edge_info, boost::no_property>’:
/usr/include/boost/pending/detail/property.hpp:94:48:   instantiated from ‘boost::detail::build_property_tag_value_alist<boost::property<boost::edge_bundle_t, edge_info, boost::no_property> >’
/usr/include/boost/pending/property.hpp:63:81:   instantiated from ‘boost::property_value<boost::property<boost::edge_bundle_t, edge_info, boost::no_property>, boost::edge_bundle_t>’
/usr/include/boost/graph/properties.hpp:448:63:   instantiated from ‘boost::graph_detail::retagged_bundle<boost::property<boost::edge_bundle_t, edge_info, boost::no_property>, boost::edge_bundle_t>’
/usr/include/boost/graph/properties.hpp:461:64:   instantiated from ‘boost::graph_detail::normal_property<edge_info, boost::edge_bundle_t>’
/usr/include/boost/graph/properties.hpp:473:12:   instantiated from ‘boost::graph_detail::edge_prop<edge_info>’
/usr/include/boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp:381:70:   instantiated from ‘boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::bidirectionalS, vertex_info, edge_info>’
/usr/include/boost/graph/properties.hpp:418:44:   instantiated from ‘boost::property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::bidirectionalS, vertex_info, edge_info>, position vertex_info::*>’
gtest.cc:30:32:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/boost/pending/property.hpp:35:7: error: ‘boost::property<Tag, T, Base>::m_value’ has incomplete type
gtest.cc:13:8: error: forward declaration of ‘struct edge_info’
gtest.cc:33:45: error: template argument 1 is invalid
```

Comment: does the error say _with Tag = ..., T = ..., Base = ..._?

Comment: @K-ballo I've included the complete error report in the question body. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a recursive type definition like

```
struct edge_info;

typedef adjacency_list<..., edge_info> graph_type;

typedef boost::property_map<graph_type, ...>::type position_map_type;

struct edge_info { map_computation<position_map_type>* c; };
```

As was mentioned in e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6517325/819272), the C++ Standard says in §17.4.3.6/2,

> In particular, the effects are undefined in the following cases:
>
> __ [..] — if an incomplete type (3.9) is used as a template argument when instantiating a template component.
>   __ [..]

Depending on what you want to accomplish (it's not entirely clear from your question), you might want to consider the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP) in which you can do something like this:

```
template<typename edge>
class some_graph_type 
{ // ... };

class my_edge_type
: 
    public some_graph_type<my_edge_type> 
{ // ... };
```

So you can have an `edge` class derive from a class template with itself as a template parameter. Similarly, you can have an `edge` class have an `edge*` member (similar to a linked-list) but not a member for which you need to know the full definition of `edge` itself first.

Comment: Thanks, I imagined that the error was mine and not of the compiler. Nonetheless I'd like to resolve the compilation error with minimal change to the code that uses graph_type. (btw: I cannot change the boost::graph type (it's a boost type) so I don't understand how the CRTP could help in my case, please explain.

Comment: @baol As I explained, if you had only an `edge*` as a member type it would work. But not if you have a member pointer with `edge` as a template parameter.

Comment: @baol Did you just revoke the "Accepted" status? Please let me know how the answer could be improved.

Comment: @TemplateTex you described the problem in great detail, but did not provide a solution. If you need more context please refer to the boost graph library documentation.