# Object containing lists of itself recursively

Tags: c++, object

For practice, I am trying to make a recursive directory parser.

For the sake of parsimony, I want to contain the result recursively too, e.g.:

```
1 class CDirectory
2 {
3     private:
4        std::string name;
5        std::vector<CDirectory> subDirectories
6    public:
7        //Various things, constructors etc. go here
8 }
```

However, [I see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517231/are-c-recursive-type-definitions-possible-in-particular-can-i-put-a-vectort) that line 5 is not supported behavior - "The C++ Standard (2003) clearly says that instantiating a standard container with an incomplete type, invokes undefined-behavior."

What, then, do I do? Is there no way to make an object contain a list of similar objects? If nothing else, I know that it is by no means illegal to make a vector of vectors, so that's an object that contains itself.

Comment: For y'all considering whether to vote to close: Do it. I agree that the other question (edited in at the top) is identical to this one.

Comment: you cannot create a vector of the same kind of vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a vector of pointers

```
std::vector<CDirectory*> subDirectories;
```

Comment: I'd consider using `std::shared_ptr<CDirectory>` instead of raw pointers to ease memory management/lifetime issues.

Comment: I don't have much experience using those. I will edit my answer...let me know if it is correct.

Comment: @sdzivanovich This is assuming shared semantics are required. Which is not clear at all.

Comment: True, I changed it back.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` is almost always better than a raw pointer.

Comment: @juanchopanza Minimally it should use some kind of smart pointer, unless there's a compelling reason to the contrary.

Comment: @sdzivanovich There's no reason to use a pointer in the first place. But if one were to use one, then the ownership should be carefully considered. OP doesn't have pointers, so the ownership is clear.

Answer (score 1):

Boost has [containers that support incomplete types](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/container/main_features.html#container.main_features.containers_of_incomplete_types). You can use one of these.

```
#include <boost/container/vector.hpp>

class CDirectory
{
   private:
       std::string name;
       boost::container::vector<CDirectory> subDirectories
   public:
       //Various things, constructors etc. go here
};
```