# Self-referential typedef without object or struct

Tags: c++

I'm fairly new to c++, and I'm trying to implement a simple trie to store a lexicon of strings, using the std::map or other c++ standard library container classes. What I'd like to be able to do is use something like

```
typedef (map<char, type_node>)* type_node;
```

for which clang++ gives me the error ' use of undeclared identifier "type_node" '.

This as opposed to a self-referential structure, such as

```
typedef struct node {
   int data;
   struct node *next;
} Node;
```

Which works fine, somehow.

Is it possible to declare self-referential types without using a class or struct?

Why does the structure work and not the recursive alias type?

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Nope. A typedef is an alias. Aliases cannot be forward-declared.

Comment: Aside: "object orientation" is not a synonym for "used a class/struct".

Comment: No, basically, the type system needs to be well-founded.

Comment: You cannot use parentheses like that in a typedef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot declare containers with incomplete types[1]. So `map<char, type_node>` is an error and consequently the alias is also an error.

In C++ all structs are implicitly typedef'd[2]. Your structure can be simplified to:

```
struct node
{
   int data;
   node * next;
};
```

Links:

1. [Are C++ recursive type definitions possible, in particular can I put a vector<T> within the definition of T?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517231/are-c-recursive-type-definitions-possible-in-particular-can-i-put-a-vectort)
2. [Difference between 'struct' and 'typedef struct' in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c)

Comment: The disadvantage of the `struct node` shown is that you don't get the mapping facilities added automatically.

Comment: Hmm what about `struct node { map<int, node*> ptr;}`