# C++ recursive type definition

Tags: c++

Why is the following code valid? The struct test contains a vector of test, so that the following code [compiles (IDEOne)](https://ideone.com/odqfCy):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct test {
    vector<test> a;
};

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    test t;
    if (t.a.size() > 0)
        return -1;
    else if (t.a[0].a[0].a.size() > 0)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

How does the compiler handle the struct so that is is possible to test for `t.a[0].a[0].a.size()`? Is there a limit on how often I could repeat the `.a[0]`?

---

Edit: This questions has an answer that claims this is undefined behaviour: [Are C++ recursive type definitions possible, in particular can I put a vector<T> within the definition of T?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6517231/3867787)

=> This is confusing

=> perhaps my question is a duplicate

Comment: The default constructor for `std::vector` does not require the template argument to be a fully qualified name.

Comment: To push things farther, `struct WTF : std::vector<WTF> {};` I use it to build [Peano's natural numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms) :D

Comment: (hint : `operator++()` is just `{push_back(*this); return *this;}`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This boils down to `vector<T>` not needing to know the size a value of type `T` occupies, which allows `T` to be an incomplete type. Essentially, the mechanism in play here is the same as in this declaration:

```
struct test {
    test* start;
    test* end;
};
```

The compiler has no problem declaring pointers to any type, as long as you promise to define it at some later point.

This behavior changes based on the template: you have no problem defining `test` with a `vector<T>`, but an `array<T,Size>` or even a `pair<T,K>` would be problematic:

```
struct broken1 {
    array<broken1,3> a; // Does not compile
};
struct broken2 {
    pair<broken2,broken2> p; // Does not compile
};
```