# Path tree to tree structure

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree

Hello suppose you have ordinary unix path tree as input (as string).

```
root 0
root/file1.txt 1
root/file2.txt 2
root/folder1 3
root/folder1/file3.txt 4
root/folder1/file4.txt 5
e.t.c.
```

What is the better way to convert this string to tree data structure?

Comment: Q: What do you mean?  Also: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205945/why-does-the-c-stl-not-provide-any-tree-containers

Comment: I have path tree as string. I need to make tree data structure (c++ class) and reflect appropriate hierachy.

Comment: I don't think there is any best way. You just have to define your tree structure and parse your file. It's normal programming work in other words, no tricks.

Comment: There is no "better" way. If you want a filesystem like tree, you need something like a dummy filesystem. Or you can just write a function that adds a full path at once. You should probably use std::map, first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now i use simple tree representation, created by myself

```
template<typename T>
class TreeNode
{
public:
    TreeNode() {};

    TreeNode(T)
    {
        value = T;
    }

    TreeNode(const T& value)
        : Value(value)
    {
    }

    T Value;
    vector<TreeNode<T>*> Children;
};
```

I don't really understand Gir's algorithm (posted above). But i suppose the solution must be the following:

```
1. Get a root node, set depth_level = 0
3. set support_node = root_node
4. for each path line
5.     determine the quantity of slashes "/", key and file(folder) name

so for example in string root/folder1/file4.txt 5, num of slashes = 2 filename = file4.txt, key = 5
       create current_node
6.     if num_of_slashes == level + 2
7.          set support_node = current_node
8.     if num_of_slashes == level + 1
9.          add children to support_node
10.    And after that we must remember all ancestors,  going down to leaves. Cuz we can  return to any ancestor.
```

For me this algorithm seems to be really complicated. I don't understand algorithm, posted above, maybe it is possible to clarify this question? Maybe the structure i use to store the tree isn't the best one?

Answer (score 1):

something like this:

create a root node for '\'

```
node=root;
token=getNextToken(inputString);
while (token){
 if (!node.childExist(token)) node.createChild(token)
 node=node.Child(token)
 token=getNextToken(inputString);
}
```

Comment: Yup - that's definitely a good algorithm for parsing the strings to build the tree.  The next question is "What do I use to implement the tree?"  That's where the link I cited above comes in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205945/why-does-the-c-stl-not-provide-any-tree-containers.  As  jahhaj said, there is no one, out of the box, built-in "Best Way".

Comment: Gir: do not allowed to use any third - party libraries. What is node in your code? I

Comment: paulsm4: i saw this link but i can't use boost graph library to solve this problem

Comment: You dont need any third party libraries - you can write a tree class yourself