# Is there any MFC / STL class that represents Binary Tree

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl, mfc, binary-tree

In MFC collection classes, we have Linked Lists, Maps, Dynamic Arrays,...

But does anyone know whether there is a wholesome class which supports Binary tree implementations and its functions in MFC (or even in STL)?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/205945/78845

Comment: I assume you mean a binary tree in the sense that you can actually enumerate nodes and request left and right children, perform various order-enumerations, etc. Is that correct? if so, then no, neither support such a construct. std::map<> and std::set<> a based on RB-balanced trees, but specific node-level querying and ordered enumeration is not provided as a feature (probably because there is little-to-no earthly reason besides academia anyone would use it).