# Is there an stl container for this hierarchical model data?

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, containers

For a platform-independent model layer, I have hierarchical data (strings, actually) that look like this:

- Item A

  - SubItem A
  - SubItem B
  - SubItem C

    - SubSubItem A
    - SubSubItem B
  - SubItem D
- Item B
- Item C

Now, within each "level" (Item, SubItem, SubSubItem, etc.) the items need to be sorted alphabetically.

Seems a simple solution would be to create a simple class with a sorted std::Vector or std::MultiMap to track its Children, and a pointer to its Parent.  (and one root item).  I would need to generally iterate through each item's children in a forward direction.

After construction/sorting, I do not need to add or delete items.  Generally small numbers of items (hundreds).

This is for model organization of the backing data of an outline-style control.

Rolling a simple class would be easy, but this is such a common pattern — isn't there already a ready-made STL container with this behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing in STL itself, but you might find this useful:

[tree.hh: an STL-like C++ tree class](http://tree.phi-sci.com/index.html)

Its API follows STL containers exactly, and it should do what you're looking for.

I believe [their example](http://tree.phi-sci.com/documentation.html) is exactly what you are asking about (a tree with strings), in fact.

Comment: thanks -- this is an elegant class.  It's licensed under GPLv2 / GPLv3.  I'm developing commercial software.  If I DO NOT modify the code in ANY WAY, am I required to distribute any source code?

Comment: Hmmm I'm not an expert at all, but it sounds like you would be [required to do just that](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#GPLInProprietarySystem). You might be able to use the [property tree class from Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/property_tree.html) instead.

Comment: @SMGreenfield - I came to the same conclusion that this class is not suitable for commercial applications.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution:

Your keys are `std::vector<GUID>`, where the `GUID` is some type (maybe a GUID, or a pointer, or a string) that uniquely identifies each element.  Children of an element simply have that elements `std::vector<GUID>` as a "prefix".

So long as your `GUID` are sortable via `operator<`, lexographic sorting on the `std::vector` will get things in the order you requested.

A `map<std::vector<GUID>, Value>` could be your container, or a `std::vector< std::pair< GUID, Value > >` that you sort by `.first` manually.

If your `GUID` type can have a "last element", you can find every child of `{x,y,z}` by finding `lower_bound` of `{x,y,z}` and `upper_bound` of `{x,y,z,last_guid}`.  Giving it a "last element" is an advantage to not using a naked pointer.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Don't mean to be curt, but that is the answer; see e.g. [Josuttis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321623215), or the standard.  You'll have to create a class which parent/child pointers along the lines you suggested and use a vector or other standard container of those.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is no, there is no tree in the STL. The patterns you suggested are fine. Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205945/why-does-the-c-stl-not-provide-any-tree-containers).