# How to store a tree like structure in STL

Tags: data-structures, stl

I need to read some data from a file that follows a tree like structure( bookmarks and I guess you can say they follow the windows explorer dir /file structure )
After reading this data needs to be applied to an identical file . Is there a quick STL structure I can use to both load the tree info from the first file and then traverse it with the second file and write it out.

Comment: _Possible Duplicate_: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205945/why-does-the-c-stl-not-provide-any-tree-containers

Comment: I agree its a duplicate all the info I needed was in there
How do I close this as a dupe