# How can I represent a key-value-tree in C++ / STL

Tags: c++, stl, shared-ptr, key-value-coding

I try to code a representation of a **tree of key-value pairs** with the option of multiple values for a key. What I try to do with that is reading a "data-tree" at the start of my program and then give each part of the program the "branch" of data it requires. The Libs I use so far are OpenCV and Intel TBB.

An example of the data in **XML** looks like this:

```
<key_1> value_1 </key_1>
<key_2> value_2 </key_2>
<!--  -->
<key_3> 
    <subkey_1> value_3 </subkey_1>
    <subkey_2> value_4 value_5 value_6 </subkey_1>
</key_3>
<key_4> value_1 </key_4>
```

So far what I came up with are two classes:

- A Class for holding a single key-value pair, named **KeyValue**
- A Class **KeyValueGroup** representing a collection of *KeyValues* and capable of holding other *KeyValueGroups*.

The Code would be:

```
class KeyValue {
    std::string mKey;
    std::vector<std::string> mValues;
}

class KeyValueGroup {
    // setters, getters, etc
    std::vector<KeyValue> mKeyValues;
    std::vector<KeyValueGroup> mKeyValueGroups;
    std::string mKey;
}
```

The values can be of different types but I convert them to std::string. My solution works, but my gut tells me this solution is probably awkward. So how would a professional tackle this problem?

Another question I ask myself is, wether I should wrap both classes in std::shared_ptr for speed (average string length is about 5 chars).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How much effort you put in depends on how performance critical this data is to your program, what access/update patterns you expect etc..

For undemanding use...

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> tree;
```

...where the `map`'s key is a concatenation of the XML-specified keys, using a suitable separator or delimiter (e.g. a space, `'|'`, `';'`...?).  `std::unordered_map` is another option.  If necessary, a "Key" class can be written to hold a `std::string` and provide some convenience functions such as stripping the trailing element etc..

If I needed something fancier, I'd consider a third-party library e.g. `boost::graph`.  See also [this question/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205945/why-does-the-c-stl-not-provide-any-tree-containers?rq=1) for background on C++ and trees.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a RapidJSON Document object.

This allows you to represent a JSON object with keys and subkeys.
Here's an example :

```
rapidjson::Document document;

// Initialise the rapid json document to an empty object
document.SetObject();

Document::AllocatorType& allocator = document.GetAllocator();

// Add parent keys
document.AddMember("key_1", "value_1", allocator);
document.AddMember("key_2", "value_2", allocator);
document.AddMember("key_3", "value_3", allocator);

// Add subkeys
document["key_3"].SetObject();
document["key_3"].AddMember("subkey_1", "value_3", allocator);
```