# STL for segment tree in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, segment-tree

Is there any STL for segment tree?

In competitive programming it takes a lot of time to code for seg tree. I wonder if there is any STL for that so that lot of time could be saved.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/205945/252576

Answer (score 12):

I assume by "segment tree" you actually mean *range tree*, which is more commonly used in programming contests than the more specialized structure for storing a set of intervals.

There is no such container in the C++ standard library but if you are competing in ACM contests you can consider writing your own and simply copying it as needed. You can find my own implementation [here](https://github.com/t3nsor/codebook/blob/master/segtree.cpp) (including lazy propagation) but if you search the web you can probably find a more generic version.

In applications where you need the sum instead of the minimum or maximum, you can use a binary indexed tree instead of a segment tree, which is faster, uses less memory, and is also easier to code (about a dozen lines or less).

Comment: Although this is totally unrelated, and I'm sorry that if it goes against SO rules, but I'm suddenly in awe of seeing your answer just above mine. I follow you on Quora as well (I'm the guy who was against letting felons vote, and had commented the same on your answer), so this was definitely a pleasant surprise.

PS: If such a comment is against the rules, let me know and I will delete it.

Answer (score 4):

There is no STL in C++ for segment tree. However, you can check out the Boost Library called [Interval Container Library (ICL)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/icl/doc/html/index.html) which should satisfy your requirements.