# storing struct into BST

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I am new to programming. My question is: is it possible to store a four-member struct into a binary search tree? I have an input txt file containing data that I have already read. The input file looks like this:

```
 30005886 Vanessa Yorson 19601202
 30007518 Cara Yarrow 19490413
 30011718 Sally Mooney 19760111
```

so this is my struct:

```
struct dataRec {
    int ssn;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    int dob;
};
```

how would I go about storing this info into a BST? Thanks!

Comment: Sure.Trees have nodes and its up to you what you want to store in those nodes.

Comment: what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is.

Just when you create the node of a tree make that node like `struct dataRec *node`;

After this , you can use malloc to allocate the memory and then you can assign the respective values.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are trying to learn binary search tree, you can use std::map to solve this problem.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map
Maps are usually implemented as red-black trees.

Red black trees are a kind of self balancing binary search tree.

STL doesn't have tree containers [Why does the C++ STL not provide any "tree" containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205945/why-does-the-c-stl-not-provide-any-tree-containers) but the functionality is available through map.

If you are using a map your problem is simple
`std::map<int, dataRec> storage;`