# Ordered Tree in C++

Tags: c++, boost, stl, tree

The C++ STL apparently is missing an ordered tree data structure. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205945/why-does-the-c-stl-not-provide-any-tree-containers). Boost is also missing an ordered tree, but it does have an "un"ordered one, [Property Tree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/property_tree.html) where the data is ordered by insertion. I want the order to be irrespective of memory.

The boost page on Property Trees says that this is conceptually the boost::ptree structure.

```
struct ptree
{
   data_type data;                         // data associated with the node
   list< pair<key_type, ptree> > children; // ordered list of named children by insertion
};
```

I want to extend boost to keep track of order.

Is this the correct way?

```
class ordered_ptree : public boost::property_tree::ptree {
public:
  ordered_ptree(int id) : _id{id}{};

 protected:
  int _id;
};
```

Comment: I'm confused. Why can't you use `std::map`?

Comment: @Pubby If I can, that would be fine. How do you setup std::map to handle root / node relationships (effectively std::tree)? That said, boost's ptree XML import will be helpful for the next step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(From the comments in your question, I understand you want something like Python's [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) but taking into account keys' relative order.)

Since none of the standard library's (or boost's) containers are exactly what you want, you might want to extend [`std::map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) (especially if you don't need all of the interface).

Say you start with

```
template<
    typename Key, 
    typename Value, 
    class Compare=std::less<Key>,
    class Alloc=std::allocator<pair<const Key, Value> >
class ordered_map
{
    // This needs to be filled.
};
```

Now inside, you can hold an insertion counter:

```
    std::size_t m_ins_count;
```

which is initialized to 0 and incremented at each insert.

Internally, your new keys will be `std::pair`s of the original key and the insertion count. Standard properties of [binary search trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) imply that nodes with keys differing only by the second `pair` item (which is the insertion count), will be consecutive in an in-order walk, which means that

1. you retain order of different keys
2. you retain order of insertion within a key
3. the operations are logarithmic time
4. traversing same-key items is (amortized) linear time

So, internally you'd have something like

```
    typedef
        std::map<
            std::pair<Key, std::size_t>,
            Value,
            lex_compare<Compare>,
            std::allocator<std::pair<std::pair<Key, std::size_t>,     Value> >
        internal_map_t;
```

(where `lex_compare<Compare>` compares first by the given functor, then by the insertion index).

---

Now you can choose a (minimal) interface, and implement it, by translating keys in the "outer world" and pairs of keys + insertion indices in the "inner world" of the tree.

If you plan on providing an iterator interface as well, you might find the [boost iterator library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/iterator/doc/) useful, as you simply want to modify `std::map`'s iterators.