# Generic vector of vector n dimensionnal

Tags: c++, vector

I try something (probably in the wrong way) but the langage and std doesn't let me do what I want.
I have a void* that can contain : `std::vector<int>` or `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` or `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>` or ... and so on. I have a dpeth variable to know how much vector level.

So I "just" want to write a method that iterate through my vector and for each element give to me a new `void*` to a `subVector` or `int`.
But I can't get generically a sub element from my vector if don't give the real type (which can be very very very long)
I'm trying to macro some typedef :

```
using DIM1 = std::vector<int>;
using DIM2 = std::vector<std::vector<int>>;
```

But I can't convert my void* to a DIMX* (without an insane switch case statement)

Any ideas, (or other ways to approach the problem)

Comment: Are the lengths the same across all dimensions?  Might be time to flatten your vectors.

Comment: "I want [...] void*" why? There is (almost) no reason to use `void*` for type erase anymore. Anyhow if you need help with the code that casts from and to `void*` you should include a [mcve] in the quesiton

Comment: what is the "something" you want to do with the vectors?

Comment: A jagged vector of arbitrary dimension (depth) is called a _tree_.  Think of it like nested folders in a file hierarchy on disk.  Consider reading [Why does the C++ STL not provide any "tree" containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205945/why-does-the-c-stl-not-provide-any-tree-containers)

Comment: Thanks for the link @Wyck it help to see other way to achieve this.
My N dimentional Matrix have all dimensions variables (not a real matrix so)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I want to create dynamically a fake matrix (any dimensions could be different) from a stream/file or whatever. So it should be generic.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I used void* because I have lot of other type that can be pointed by this pointer (Object, primitive type, simple vector, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, prefer a `std::any` (rather than `void*`) to allow a variable to take on values of any type.

Here is a way to describe your strongly-typed N-dimensional jagged vector.

```
#include <vector>
#include <any>

template<int n, typename T> 
class DIM : public std::vector<typename DIM<n - 1, T>::type> {
public:
    typedef std::vector<typename DIM<n - 1, T>::type> type;
};

template<typename T>
class DIM<1, T> : public std::vector<T> {
public:
    typedef std::vector<T> type;
};

int main()
{
    // Let's populate a minimal 4-D example object.
    DIM<4, int> foo;
    foo.push_back(DIM<3,int>());
    foo[0].push_back(DIM<2,int>());
    foo[0][0].push_back(DIM<1, int>());
    foo[0][0][0].push_back(1);

    // example of stashing it in a std::any
    std::any idk = foo;
    
    // example of extracting the contents of idk
    DIM<4, int> bar;
    bar = std::any_cast<DIM<4, int>>(idk);
}
```

(*Above example requires C++17.*)

But you still are required to know the dimension at compile time. This doesn't get you a run-time-variable number of dimensions (variable depth).

If you require variable depth at run-time then look for a [*tree*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205945/why-does-the-c-stl-not-provide-any-tree-containers) data structure.

Comment: Thanks, it's a great step forward for me but I can't known the dimension at compile time. I think I had to re think my container (or use a lot of switch :s)

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is a better way for you to achieve what you want to do, but you can use templates like:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <cstddef>

template <size_t DEPTH>
struct helper;

template <>
struct helper<1>{
    using type = std::vector<int>;
};

template <size_t DEPTH>
struct helper {
    using type = std::vector<typename helper<DEPTH-1>::type>;
};

template <size_t DEPTH>
typename helper<DEPTH>::type* cast_to_vector(void* data){
    return static_cast<typename helper<DEPTH>::type*>(data);
}


int main() {

    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> vec{};
    void * example = &vec;
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>* vec_prt = cast_to_vector<3>(example);
    return 0;
}
```

This will recursively construct the type you want. You can also ignore the `cast_to_vector` function and use the `helper` classes.

If these are not compile time constants then this might be more problematic. One easy, but potentially very messy method of working with this is by using a custom datatype, like:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class Tree : public std::vector<Tree<T>>{
    public:
        operator T&() { return val; }
        Tree& operator =(const T& new_val) {
            this->val = new_val;
            return *this;
        }
    private:
        T val;
};
```

This implementation does miss a lot of things you'd want, but it does work for demonstration. You can then access this iteratively like `a[0][2][3] = 10;`
An other option (especially useful if the data's size is constant), would be to implement a new object, something like:

```cpp
template <typename T, bool ret_self = true>
class Tree {
    public:
        Tree(const std::vector<size_t>& arr_sizes)
            : data_size{arr_sizes}
            , data{std::make_shared<T[]>(prod(arr_sizes))}
            , array{data.get()} {}

         Tree<T>& operator[] (size_t index) {
             std::vector<size_t> new_sizes = data_size;
             new_sizes.erase(new_sizes.begin());
             if (new_sizes.empty())
                return Tree<T>(new_sizes, this->data, array + prod(new_sizes)*index);
            return Tree<T,false>(new_sizes, this->data, array + prod(new_sizes)*index);
        }
    private:
        Tree(std::vector<size_t>&& arr_sizes, const std::shared_ptr<T>& d, T* arr)
            : data_size{arr_sizes}
            , data_size{d}
            , array{arr} {}
        std::vector<size_t> data_size;
        std::shared_ptr<T> data;
        T* array;
};

template <typename T>
class Tree<T,false> {
    public:
        Tree(const std::vector<size_t>& arr_sizes)
            : data_size{arr_sizes}
            , data{std::make_shared<T[]>(prod(arr_sizes))}
            , array{data.get()} {}

         T& operator[] (size_t index) {
             return this->array[index];
        }
    private:
        Tree(std::vector<size_t>&& arr_sizes, const std::shared_ptr<T>& d, T* arr)
            : data_size{arr_sizes}
            , data_size{d}
            , array{arr} {}
        std::vector<size_t> data_size;
        std::shared_ptr<T> data;
        T* array;
};
```

As stated however this does not work if the data's size is ever modified, and also it might be a bit convoluted.

Comment: nice answer, thank you, but because I can't known the DEPTH at compile, I will still be stuck with this containers. I think I had to change lot of things :s

Comment: @zzDiego Added some alternative ways of approaching the issue

Answer (score 0):

You should use a flat vector.

The big advantage of `std::vector` is that its elements are stored in contiguous memory. The big disadvantage of nested `std::vector` is that the innermost elements are not stored in contiguous memory.

Consider how a `std::vector<int>` looks like roughly:

```
struct fake_vector {
     int* data;
     size_t size;
};
```

Internally it has a pointer to heap allocated elements:

```
|---------|            elements
| vector  | --->   [0][1][2][3]...........
|---------|
```

A `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` however looks like this

```
|--------------|       |--------------|            some elements
| outer vector | --->  | inner vector | ---->      [0][1][2].....
|--------------|       |--------------|        
                       |--------------|            some elements
                       | inner vector | ---->      [0][1][2]....
                       |--------------|
                       | ....         |
                       |--------------|
```

The inner vectors are stored contiguously, but the elements on the lowest level are scattered around in memory.

Using a flat vector in place of a N-dimensional array is just a matter of index transformations. The following isnt the nicest way to do it, but I hope it suffices to illustrate the idea:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct N_dims {
    N_dims(std::initializer_list<size_t> d) : dims(d) {
        sizes.resize(dims.size());
        auto it = dims.rbegin();
        auto its = sizes.rbegin();
        *its = *it;
        for (++it; it != dims.rend(); ++it) { 
            auto prev = *its;
            ++its;
            *its = *it * prev;                        
        }
        data.resize(sizes[0]);
    }
    int& operator()(std::vector<size_t> index) {
        auto it = index.rbegin();
        size_t flat_index = *it;
        auto its = sizes.rbegin();
        for (++it; it != index.rend(); ++it) {
            flat_index += *it * *its;
            ++its;
        }
        return data[flat_index];
    }

    std::vector<size_t> dims;
    std::vector<int> data;
    std::vector<size_t> sizes;
};


int main()
{
    N_dims nd{2,3,4};
    nd({0,0,0}) = 1;
    nd({0,0,3}) = 2;
    nd({0,1,0}) = 3;
    nd({0,1,3}) = 4;
    nd({0,2,3}) = 5;
    nd({1,0,0}) = 6;  // first element of second 3x4 submatrix. 
                      // Its "flat index" is 1*3*4 + 0*4 + 0 = 12
    nd({1,0,3}) = 7;
    nd({1,2,3}) = 8;
    for (const auto& e : nd.data) {
        std::cout << e << " ";
    }
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/7rM8YTEY4):

```
1 0 0 2 3 0 0 4 0 0 0 5 6 0 0 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 8
```